# Is "c'est ce que c'est" ever used in conversation?

Tags: traduction

In English, the phrase "It is what it is." can be used colloquially to reinforce a prior statement or assertion.  For example, "I know you feel differently but it is what it is.".  In French, "c'est ce que c'est" is the literal translation and I'm wondering if it's ever used or whether something like "C'est comme ça." or something else is used instead.

Comment: [P'têt bien qu'oui et p'têt bien qu'non](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99oui,_p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99non) ;)

Comment: Coller  "I know you feel differently but it is what it is." dans https://www.deepl.com/translator et cliquer sur les deux *c'est* pour avoir des traductions plus subtiles ou idiomatiques.

Answer (score 1):

there is a song by "Les Rita Mitsouko" its name is "c'est comme ça"
I think using "c'est comme ça" is most familiar.

you can see the song lyric here:
https://g.co/kgs/Js5xwz

Comment: It does really give an answer to the question / Ca ne répond pas vraiment à la question posée.

Comment: Your expression does answer the question, but the use that has been made of it in the Rita Mitsouko song is different, the meaning is factual: it is an  answer to the question "How is it", and after answering "c'est comme ça", one can go about showing how it is. Another context for this meaning is that of someone making a description; then someone else who agrees with them will say "C'est comme ça!" so as to say that they agree with the desdcription. Remove your Rita Mitsouko reference and you might get points.

Comment: Thank you @LPH, your answer was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways exist to translate this expression but the literal translation won't do ("c'est ce que c'est").

There is the expression "C'est comme ça" which has been proposed but on the basis of an apparent misunderstanding (**[user  Hadi](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51900/17649)**). It's an expression that makes the tone of the person using it a little blunt; also it can be  ambiguous, so that it is better to add something so as to avoid possible harshness of tone.

There is the expression "*Prendre son parti de qqc., en prendre son parti.*".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parti)) *Prendre son parti de qqc., en prendre son parti.*  **Accepter (ce qu'on ne peut éviter, quelque chose de pénible, de déplaisant)**. Synon. s'accommoder; se résigner.
> • La déception de mon corps, j'en prenais mon parti; mais ce vide, j'avais de la peine à le supporter (Beauvoir,Mandarins, 1954, p.309)
> • ... on restera jusqu'à la fin sans savoir à quoi s'en tenir; en attendant, la vie continue, tout comme si de rien n'était. Et de cela aussi on prend son parti! Comme de tout le reste... comme de tout. Gide,Faux-monn., 1925, p.1189.

- I know you feel differently but it is what it is.
  *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais il faut en prendre notre parti.*

*Other possibilities*

- *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais c'est comme ça, [nous sommes / on est] différents.*
- *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais c'est une différence dont il faut [nous  accommoder / qu'on s'accommode].*
- *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais c'est une situation [que nous devons/qu'on doit/que l'on doit] accepter.*
- *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais c'est [un état de chose / une chose] [que nous devons/qu'on doit/que l'on doit] accepter.*
- *Je sais que tu ne pense pas comme moi, mais c'est une situation à laquelle [nous devons nous / on doit se] résigner.*

Note     The form with "on" is usual; that with "nous" is rare.